# Reading Polar RR files with RHRV package in R

Tags: plot, heartrate

I am trying to better understand the RHRV package and am using some Polar RR files to go through some of the functions. I am following along with the RHRV quick start guide, and am trying to take an RR file that I have from an exercise session where I wore a Polar Heart Rate monitor, and plot the data and run the `CreateTimeAnalysis()` function.

One of the issues I am currently having is that, after importing the RR file using the code below

```
hrv.data = CreateHRVData()
hrv.data = SetVerbose(hrv.data, TRUE)
hrv.data = LoadBeatRR(hrv.data, RecordName = 'half_rr.csv')
```

and trying to run the `hrv.data = FilterNIHR(hrv.data)` function, it returns with:

```
> hrv.data = FilterNIHR(hrv.data)
 Filtering non-interpolated Heart Rate 
 Number of original beats: 20225 
 Number of accepted beats: 1
```

From there, if I run the `hrv.data = InterpolateNIHR(hrv.data)`, there is only one heart beat that is accepted, so the plot is essentially empty, and I am unable to proceed with the `CreateTimeAnalysis()` function. The file that I am using is an RR file from a long exercise session, so there was just over 2 hours of collection. Any help would be great, just trying to better understand this package.

Thanks!